# Loading data from SQL Server to Elasticsearch

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, amazon-redshift

Looking for suggesting on loading data from SQL Server into Elasticsearch or any other data store. The goal is to have transactional data available in real time for Reporting.

We currently use a 3rd party tool, in addition to SSRS, for data analytics. The data transfer is done using daily batch jobs and as a result, there is a 24 hour data latency.

We are looking to build something out that would allow for more real time availability of the data, similar to SSRS, for our Clients to report on. We need to ensure that this does not have an impact on our SQL Server database.

My initial thought was to do a full dump of the data, during the weekend, and writes, in real time, during weekdays.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**ElasticSearch's** main use cases are for providing search type capabilities on top of unstructured large text based data. For example, if you were ingesting large batches of emails into your data store every day, **ElasticSearch** is a good tool to parse out pieces of those emails based on rules you setup with it to enable searching (and to some degree querying) capability of those email messages.

If your data is already in SQL Server, it sounds like it's structured already and therefore there's not much gained from **ElasticSearch** in terms of reportability and availability. Rather you'd likely be introducing extra complexity to your data workflow.

If you have structured data in SQL Server already, and you are experiencing issues with reporting directly off of it, you should look to building a **data warehouse** instead to handle your reporting. SQL Server comes with a number of features out of the box to help you replicate your data for this very purpose. The three main features to accomplish this that you could look into are [**AlwaysOn Availability Groups**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), [**Replication**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15), or [**SSIS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver15).

Each option above (in addition to other out-of-the-box features of SQL Server) have different pros and drawbacks. For example, **AlwaysOn Availability Groups** are very easy to setup and offer the ability to automatically failover if your main server had an outage, but they clone the entire database to a replica. **Replication** let's you more granularly choose to only copy specific Tables and Views, but then you can't as easily failover if your main server has an outage. So you should read up on all three options and understand their differences.

Additionally, if you're having specific performance problems trying to report off of the main database, you may want to dig into the root cause of those problems first before looking into replicating your data as a solution for reporting (although it's a fairly common solution). You may find that a simple architectural change like using a **columnstore index** on the correct Table will improve your reporting capabilities immensely.

---

I've been down both pathways of implementing **ElasticSearch** and a **data warehouse** using all three of the main data synchronization features above, for structured data and unstructured large text data, and have experienced the proper use cases for both. One **data warehouse** I've managed in the past had Tables with billions of rows in it (each Table terabytes big), and it was highly performant for reporting off of on fairly modest hardware in AWS (we weren't even using **Redshift**).

Comment: Hi J.D., thanks for the detailed info. Its very helpful. I don't think AlwaysOn Availability Groups would be suitable as it is taking a copy of the whole db. We have an ETL process, which is basically a stored proc that transforms the data from the SQL Server db, before loading into the data store. I will have a read through Replication.

Comment: @rrmave No problem. **AlwaysOn Availability Groups** is definitely the simplest to setup, but I guess the saying "*storage is cheap*" kind of died out when AWS started becoming popular lol. **Replication** has been around a while though, so it's tried and true and definitely useful. It can attain near sub-second real-time synchronization of the data when setup properly. There's 4 kinds of **Replication** but you likely want to use **Transactional Replication** and/or **Snapshot Replication**, depending on your schema and how real-time you need the data to be in sync.